# How to indicate a method in a controller is not an action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have a situation where I want to use a page specific controller. In that controller I have an action method and a bunch of helper methods. In real life the helper methods are inherited from a `BaseController` but to make things simple lets assume I just have one helper method directly in my controller class like so:

```
[Route("/dev/test")]
public class TestController : Controller {

    public IActionResult Get() {
        return UnprocessedEntityResult();
    }

    //Some helper method that I don't want to be considered an 
    //action method by the routing engine.
    public IActionResult UnprocessedEntityResult() {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity);
    }
}
```

I specifically want to use attribute based routing and I want that attribute based route specified at the **class** level.

Given the situation as coded above, a `AmbiguousActionException` will be thrown when the `/dev/test` route is accessed and it will indicate that

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched.  The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> App.Dev.TestController.Get
>  
>   App.Dev.TestController.UnprocessedEntityResult

How can I tell the routing engine that `UnprocessedEntityResult()` is not an action method? I assume that there must be some attribute that I can apply to the method but I have have not been able to locate it.

Comment: look up the `NonAction` attribute. or you can also make the action protected. It will be visible to derived types but wont confuse the route table

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look up the [`[NonAction]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nonactionattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0) attribute.

> Indicates that a controller method is not an action method.

```
[Route("/dev/test")]
public class TestController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        return UnprocessedEntityResult();
    }

    [NonAction]
    public IActionResult UnprocessedEntityResult() {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity);
    }
}
```

or you can also make the action protected.

```
[Route("/dev/test")]
public class TestController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        return UnprocessedEntityResult();
    }

    protected IActionResult UnprocessedEntityResult() {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity);
    }
}
```

It will be visible to derived types but wont confuse the route table